# Windows 7 frozen after opening the first web URL on StackExchange

Tags: windows-7, firefox, freeze

This scenario:

- reboot
- do anything I want, including using Firefox
- open first URL on SE by any means (shortcut, link, history).

When the first StackExchange HTML page is opened using Firefox:

- FF freezes
- Mouse and whole system are frozen
- Keyboard, including Windows key, doesn't work

The system remains frozen for 30 seconds to a minute (heavy disk use), then resumes working with the page displayed. No other impact, just this delay.

Accessing other SE contents won't create any problem, even if FF is closed and reopened. This is strictly limited to the first URL after a reboot.

Maybe linked to using a resource (profile image or image) from `imgur.com`.

---

Windows 7, up to date.
FF last revision, with well-known addons, including ads, tracker, and flash blockers, and Stylish (deactivating all addons doesn't change anything).

Any idea about the reason/solution, or the method to nail the culprit down?

Update:

I pressed <kbd>f12</kbd> (developer tools) Net > All as suggested.

First I read this page and there was no problem at all (?), then https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27292/how-does-an-airplane-do-a-kulbit-manoeuvre and the problem was there.

I had this network traffic:

[image]

All GET above the read line were displayed before the freeze, these below the red line were displayed after a 30+s freeze.

In particular there are 3 resources from mathjax.org that seems really late. GET responses seems normal.

I don't know what is the vertical red line.

Comment: Next time open the SE URL and immediately hit <f12> (developer tools) Net > All. See if that gives any clues.

Comment: Thanks, good idea. First I read this page and there was no problem at all (?), then [that one](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27292/how-does-an-airplane-do-a-kulbit-manoeuvre) and the problem was there.I had [this network traffic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lH4OH.png), All GET above the read line were displayed before the freeze, these below the red line were displayed after a 30+s freeze. In particular there are 3 resources from `mathjax.org` that seems really late. GET responses seems normal. I don't know what is the vertical red line.

Comment: I updated the question with your test results.

Comment: I get a similar delay. It seems to be very slow downloading .woff font files :/

Comment: Thanks David. I'm really surprised you get this same problem. Is you OS also frozen (mouse, keyboard, etc) while waiting?

Comment: No. Not completely frozen. But the content from cdn.mathjax.org is failing to download.

Comment: What else are you doing in the background network wise? Do you get similar freezes in Chrome or IE? Is there anything relevant in the event viewer at the time of the freeze?

Comment: @Burgi: It happens at any time when the URL is first accessed with FF after a reboot. No particular network activity. Can't make sense of the events, too obscure, no red error. I've noticed huge number of 5447 event, and deactivated audit for this.  I have no other browser configured.

Comment: I have also had this problem with recent FF versions. By checking the activity using the Web Console, (probably the same detail as Network), it seems to hang the first time downloadable web fonts are accessed. After that, no further problem until the system is restarted. Before this started with Firefox, I had the same problem when starting Adobe Photoshop Elements (system would hang when loading the available fonts). It seems to be checking the system fonts somehow. Not sure how to check further, since even Resource Monitor in Windows Task Manager freezes.

Comment: Also, are you running any antivirus software?

Comment: @user3169. Thanks for the confirmation and interesting detail. As the last resource obtained in normal time, according to FF is `mathjax-editing.en.js` from `cdn.sstatic.net`, the problem could be a disk search called from here. I'll investigate in this direction. Yes I run KIS.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help. It seems I've **temporary solved** this problem by allowing **3rd party cookies** and DOM storage for `SE` and `mathjax.org` in [Cookie Controller](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/cookie-controller/). It's temporary because I don't see why it works (no additional cookie created, and none from `mathjax.org`), though a value in a cookie could be used to indicate whether `mathjax` must perform the --likely initial and single--scan/download for fonts or not.

Comment: I think you will find it happens on other sites though (for me almost always on https://www.icloud.com/). Interesting as I run Kaspersky AV too. My guess is it has some involvement in this, though the problem seems too benign to take up with them, and would be difficult to document. You can also stop this problem by setting *gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled* in config. settings to false, though you will loose them everywhere.